# Relative rate of change for process spanning > 15 orders of magnitude

Tags: graphing-functions

I am trying to form a method for finding if plotted data is in equilibrium. In most cases calculating linear least squares and checking for the slope is enough. However I am now plotting data that span over 15 orders of magnitude from 1 down to ^-15. Well down there the slope is going to be very small in any case so just evaluating if the slope is smaller that something will not work.

How do I check for relative change that doesn't depend on the magnitude of the value. Do I just divide the change (of duration z) by the average of Y values of the duration z? Intuitively that seems to be some sort unitless relative change in the duration z.

1 to 0.9 in one second = 10.5% change/s

0.1 to 0.09 in one second = 10.5% change/s

0.000 000 000 000 001 to 0.000 000 000 000 000 9 in one second = 10.5% change/s

Is it this simple or am I missing something?

Comment: A relative change from `a` to `b` in percentage would be calculated as follows: `100 (b/a - 1)`. In each of your examples, one would end up with - 10 % relative change per second.

Comment: Look at the change of the logarithm of the function.

Comment: Roman, I don't speak math. From my perspective, I do not have function, only X,Y data points.

Comment: If you're just trying to visually see convergence, then you could replace `ListPlot` with `ListLogPlot`. If you're trying to measure relative slope, then convert the data set `A={{x1,y1},{x2,y2},...}` into `B={#[[1]], Log[#[[2]]]} & /@ A` before making any measurements.

Answer (score 1):

I take amount z of points covering the desired span of time from the end of the data.

Adjust x/time values so the data starts from 0

Calculate linear least squares

Relative change in the given sample duration = ((Slope * Duration + Offset) / Offset) - 1

(Thanks Henrik)